# Exoplayer Background: how to set a background for exoplayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I'm development a app with a m3u8 transmission using exoplayer, and some times my transmission is offline, so a need to show a background image with it happenes, and i now find no options to solve this. The only thing with i can find is a shutter_background_color   propertieswho define a color of the background player, but this not solve my problem. I need to show a bitmap image.

Please help!!!

```
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/pl_aovivo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:resize_mode="fit"
        app:use_artwork="true"
        app:shutter_background_color="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use artwork for this. The best you can do is to add an invisible ImageView inside the layout that host your PlayerView and just turn it visible when onPlayerError occurs.

Comment: You are right, I spent a long time reading docs and learned you can override the exoplayerview.xml, but this solution is so much easier. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have to set place holder image on to exo player than use below code:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:default_artwork="@drawable/default_media_artwork"
        app:use_artwork="true"
        app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
        app:show_buffering="when_playing" />
```